# Function continuous Uryson's lemma?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

when we proved Uryson's lemma we checked that the function $f:X \rightarrow [0,1]$, where $X$ is a $T_4$ space, i continuous by checking whether $f^{-1}([0,a))$ and $f^{-1}((b,1])$ are open. $f$ is the function that separates two closed sets. What I don't understand is: Why is it sufficient to check these intervals? Normally, I would have expected that we need to check ALL open sets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those half-open intervals $[0,a)$, $(b,1]$ form a subbasis of $[0,1]$ with the subspace topology (equivalently, order topology).

Comment: ah, so it is generally sufficient to check continuity on a basis or subbasis?

Comment: How does the collection $C$ of all sets of the forms $[0,a),(b,1]$, satisfy the property that given $B_1,B_2 \in C$, such that $x\in {B_1\cap B_2}$, there exists $B_3\in C$ such that $x\in B_3\subset {B_1\cap B_2}$?

Comment: @ShalinDoctor you're thinking of a basis; I am referring to a subbasis.

Comment: @Lipschitz, yes, it is necessary and sufficient for each $f^{-1}(B)$ to be open for every subbasis (or basis) element $B$ in order for $f$ to be continuous.  Let me know if you want me to prove these facts.  Ultimately, they have to do with the fact that $f^{-1}\left( \bigcup_\alpha{X_\alpha}\right)=\bigcup_{\alpha}{f^{-1}(U_\alpha)}$ and $f^{-1}(X\cap Y)=f^{-1}(X)\cap f^{-1}(Y)$ in general for all functions.

Comment: no thank you, I think I see why this is so...